# Is there any way to check if a field is able to be converted into a timestamp in postgres

Tags: postgresql

In T-SQL, you can do something like:

```
Select from Table where dateField is Date = true;
```

Is there some way to do this in postgres. Specifically,

```
Select * from "Table" where to_timestamp("dateField", 'MM-DD-YYYY 24HH:MI') is Possible;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be storing dates or timestamp in varchar columns in the first place (if you had you wouldn't be needing this workaround).

You can easily create a function that checks this:

```
create or replace function is_date(to_test varchar, format varchar)
  returns boolean
  language plpgsql
as
$$
declare  
  temp_result timestamp;
begin 
  temp_result := to_timestamp(to_test, format);
  return true;
exception 
  when others then
    return false;
end;
$$
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Select 
from some_table 
where is_date(some_column, 'MM-DD-YYYY 24HH:MI');
```

You can also extend the function to test for different date/timestamp formats.

But the best way to avoid this, is to use a `date` or `timestamp` column right from the beginning.

Comment: I hear you! I am working with data imported from a CSV file and am trying to get it in good format!

Comment: @abe3: that is indeed one of the exceptions to the rule ;)

Comment: A regex would be an option if the expected format is known. OTOH, a regex would be nasty if you couldn't assume some sanity in the data and had to range check the numbers.

Comment: @muistooshort: A regex will never be able to catch Februar 31st or even correctly decide if Februar 29th is valid or not.

Comment: Hence the "couldn't assume some sanity in the data and had to range check the numbers" qualifier.